# texcl option to listing package's lstset - not working in block comments

Tags: fonts, listings

I am using the `listings` package to typeset code listings.

I am further using the `texcl` option in my `\lstset` (`\lstset{texcl}`) so that I can write TeX code, including math, in comments.

However, this does not work in block comments.

Consider the following MWE (well, mostly minimal):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zi4} % if you want a \ttfamily font with bold, italic
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily,
  texcl,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
// This is a comment with \TeX: $2^3 = 8$.
/* This is a block comment with \TeX: $2^3 = 8$ */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output of the above code fragment, showing that the math is rendered as desired in the // comment, but not in the /* comment */]

I've tried this in `language=Java` as well, with the same results. (You need some `language` set so it can recognize comments.)

Since it also appears to be messing up the columns, I tried adding `columns=fullflexible`, which solves the columns issue but still doesn't allow the TeX comment lines.

I can tell that it realizes that it's a comment, because it's not `\ttfamily`, and writing some keywords like `/* int */` doesn't get it bolded as a keyword. But the TeX code is not working.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is `texcl`'s expected behaviour. See the very beginning of subsection 4.14 in the listings documentation:

> Note: Any escape to LaTeX may disturb the column alignment since the
>   package can’t control the spacing there.
>
> `texcl`=⟨`true`|`false`⟩ or `texcl`
>   false activates or deactivates LaTeX comment lines. If activated,
>   comment line delimiters are printed as usual, but the comment line
>   text (up to the end of line) is read as LATEX code and typeset in
>   comment style.

There you have it: `texcl` only affects line comments (or more precisely, to-end-of-line comments), *not* block comments. One workaround is to manually escape to LaTeX where needed inside block comments. Note that, in order to get a consistent comment style in line comments and in block comments, you need to apply your comment style at the beginning of those escapes to LaTeX; you can use the `escapebegin` key for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zi4} % if you want a \ttfamily font with bold, italic
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily,
  texcl,
  escapechar =`,
  escapebegin=\lst@commentstyle,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
// This is a comment with \TeX: $2^3 = 8$.
/* This is a block comment with `\TeX: $2^3 = 8$` */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```